# My ArcSegment doesn't actualize on Xamarin.Ios

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, path, xamarin.ios

```
<Path x:Name="PathCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="17" StrokeLineJoin="Round" TranslationX="125" TranslationY="530">
                    <Path.Data >
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0, 0" >
                                <ArcSegment  x:Name="CircleClim" Size="80, 80"
                                Point="32, -64" 
                                IsLargeArc="False" 
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
```

Here's my problem, I can't update an arcSegment, I have created an arcSegment and in function of the temperature I need to change the point. I can display it the first time when I load the app but when I change the point nothing happens, it doesn't change on my screen, but with Console.WriteLine I can see that my point change.

```
private void SwitchCircleClim()
    {
        double radius = 80;
        double angle = (10-temp)*9*Math.PI/180;

        double x = 80 +(radius * Math.Cos(angle));
        double y = (radius * Math.Sin(angle));
        CircleClim.Point=new Point(x, y);   
        Console.WriteLine(CircleClim.Point.X);
        Console.WriteLine(CircleClim.Point.Y);

    }
```

The hot reload is not enable on this ArcSegment: "Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.HotReload.Translations.resources'", so if I want to change point, I need to reload the app, and if I launch it on UWP instead of Ios, I get this error: "Loading symbols ignored. The module is optimized and the 'Only my code' debugger option is enabled." but if I unclick 'just my code' still nothing update. Do you have an idea to update my ArcSegment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can reproduce. The workaround is to remove it and add it in code behind again.

Here is an example.

Suppose the **Path** is in a StackLayout:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mystack" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300">
    <Path x:Name="PathCircle1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="17" 
    ......the same as your code here
   
    </Path>
</StackLayout>
```

And in code behind,

```
private void SwitchCircleClim()
{
    // first remove it
    mystack.Children.Remove(PathCircle1);


    // create a new one
    PathSegmentCollection pathSegments = new PathSegmentCollection();
    ArcSegment arcSegment = new ArcSegment()
    {
        Size = new Size(80, 80),
        Point = new Point(50, 50),
        IsLargeArc = false,
        SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise

    };
    pathSegments.Add(arcSegment);
    PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
    pathFigure.Segments = pathSegments;
    PathFigureCollection pathFigures = new PathFigureCollection();
    pathFigures.Add(pathFigure);


    Path PathCircle = new Path()
    {
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black),
        StrokeThickness = 17,
        StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
        TranslationX = 0,
        TranslationY = 0
    };

    PathCircle.Data = new PathGeometry()
    {
        Figures = pathFigures,
    };
    

    // then add it again
    mystack.Children.Add(PathCircle);
}
```

**Note**: Since this method draws arcsegment in code behind, that means you could reuse this part of code for initialising or modifying the arc and don't have to use xaml part to draw arc again. That would make the code more clean.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it help, that's working now !